# How to deal with a bad char in a shellcode buffer overflow?

Tags: security, assembly, buffer-overflow, exploit, shellcode

So I got recently interested in buffer overflow and many tutorials and recourses online have this CTF like attack where you need to read the content of a flag file (using cat for example).

So I started looking online for assembly examples of how to do this and I came accross sites like [this](https://masterccc.github.io/tools/shellcode_gen/) or shell-storm where there are plenty of examples on how to do this.

So I generated my exploit and got this machine code (it basically executes a shell doing cat flag):

```
shellcode = b'\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x63\x61\x74\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x68\x66\x6c\x61\x67\x89\xe1\x50\x51\x53\x89\xe1\x31\xc0\x83\xc0\x0b\xcd\x80'
```

The problem is that, thanks to stepping in with GDB to debug the problem, I noticed that my buffer doesn't get copied starting with *\x0b* towards the end of the shell code. I know the problem is there because if I change it to say *\x3b* then it works (with the rest of my exploits not copied here) even if it obviously crashes when it reaches the wrong value there but at least the whole buffer gets copied. Now doing some research it seems like *\x0b* is a "bad char" which can cause issues and should be avoided. Having said this I don't understand how:

- All those online and even university tutorials use that shell code
  for this exact task.
- How to potentially fix this. Is it even possible without completely
  change the assembly code?

I will add that I am on Ubuntu and trying to make this work on 64 bits.

Comment: As far as I know, 0xb is not a problematic char but it **depends** on which functions does the copy. You can work around it by using instructions that don't have a 0xb in their encoding (e.g. to make 0xb use 0xa and an `inc` or other similar arithmetic/logic tricks).

Comment: What ISA is this shellcode for?  AArch64?  RISC-V64?  x86-64?  Techniques to avoid certain bytes in machine code obviously depend strongly on the ISA.  You should replace the [security] tag with x86-64 or whichever is appropriate.

Comment: As Margaret says, look at the vulnerable code that copies your exploit data into the too-small buffer.  What is its condition for stopping?  If it's something like `strcpy`, then any char except `\0` is fine, and this may be the sort of vulnerability that your sources have in mind to exploit.  If it's something like `scanf("%s",...)`, then it will stop when it encounters whitespace, and `\x0b` is a whitespace character in ASCII (vertical tab).  So if that's what you're exploiting, then yes, you need to rewrite your code to avoid any bytes that are whitespace characters.

Comment: Sometimes this can be done with minor tweaks, sometimes it may require a "complete change" as you say.  It really varies.

Comment: If you would add to your question the code you're trying to exploit, you may get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that's special about byte `0x0b` is it's ASCII Vertical Tab, which is considered a whitespace character.

So I'm going to make a wild guess that the code you're exploiting looks something like

```
// Dangerous code, DO NOT USE
char buf[TOO_SMALL];
scanf("%s", buf);
```

since `scanf("%s")` is a commonly (mis)used input mechanism that stops when it hits whitespace.  If so, then if your shellcode contains `0x0b` or any other whitespace character, it will get truncated.

To your first question, as to "why do other tutorials use shellcode like this", they may be thinking instead of exploiting code like

```
// Dangerous code, DO NOT USE
char buf[TOO_SMALL];
gets(buf);
```

where `gets()` will not stop reading at `0x0b` but only at newline `0x0a`.  Or maybe they are thinking of a buffer filled by `strcpy()` which will only stop at `0x00`, or maybe a buffer filled by `read()` with a user-controlled size which will read the full amount of data no matter what bytes it contains.  So the question of which characters are "bad" depends on what the vulnerable code actually does.

As to how to handle it, well, you need to modify your shellcode to use only instructions that don't contain any whitespace bytes.  This sort of thing is more an art than a science; you have to know your instruction set well, and be creative in thinking about alternative instruction sequences to achieve the desired result.  Sometimes you may be able to do it with minor tweaks; other times a wholesale rewrite may be needed.  It really varies.

In this case, luckily the `0x0b` is the only whitespace character in the whole code, and it appears in the instruction

```
83C00B  add eax, 0x0b
```

Since `eax` was previously zeroed, the goal is to load it with the value `0xb` which is the system call number of `execve`.  When the "bad byte" appears as part of immediate data, it is usually not too hard to find another way to get that data to where it needs to go.  (Life is harder when the bad byte is part of the opcode itself.)  In this case, a simple solution is to take advantage of two's complement, and write instead

```
83E8F5  sub eax, -0x0b
```

The single byte `-0x0b = 0xf5` gets sign-extended to 32 bits and used as the value to subtract, which leaves `0x0b` in `eax` as desired.  Of course there are lots of other ways, some of which may have smaller code size; I'll leave this to your ingenuity.

Answer (score 0):

To find out the "bad char" for the shellcode is an important step to exploit an overflow vulneribility.

first, you have to figure out how many bits the target can be overflow (this field is also for the shellcode). if this zone is big enough and you can use all the "char"(google bad char from \x01 to \xff. \x00 is bad char) to act as shellcode send to target.

Then you can get find the Register to see what the char left.(if the zone is not big enough for all the chars you can send just some chars one time and repeat)

you can follow this https://netsec.ws/?p=180.